How to pass data back to the previous screen in when navigating back?
I have two Flutter screens: Screen A and Screen B.
I navigate from Screen A to Screen B using Navigator.push.
When I return from Screen B to Screen A, I want to send some data back to Screen A and handle it there.
Can you please suggest me best way to get that data ?

if you are working on small project with less screens then pass data from B to A with Navigator.pop('your_data') and fetch data to A screen with Navigator.push().then(value){}

https://docs.flutter.dev/ui/navigation

I Found this answer
Here is the correct way to receive the data from the previous screen
class ScreenA extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ScreenAState createState() => _ScreenAState();
}

class _ScreenAState extends State<ScreenA> {
  String results = 'Initial Data';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Screen A')),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Text(
              results,
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
            ),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () async {
                // Navigate to ScreenB and await the result
                var receivedValue = await Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => ScreenB()),
                );

                // Refresh the widget with the returned value
                if (receivedValue != null) {
                  setState(() {
                    results = receivedValue;
                  });
                }
              },
              child: Text('Go to Screen B'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ScreenB extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Screen B')),
      body: Center(
        child: ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            // Return data to Screen A and pop this screen
            Navigator.pop(context, 'Updated Data from Screen B');
          },
          child: Text('Send Data Back to Screen A'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

